# Creating and deploying an ActiveX control in .NET

Tags: .net, installation, activex, browser

Since there is apparently no [Flash control that can accept bitmap pastes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295524/website-image-manager-with-copypaste-flash), I want to think about writing one myself. I'd rather not use Flash though, so I though about using .NET.

Now I believe the correct terminology for a native code control that can be downloaded and run in the browser is "ActiveX control". So my question is, can I create such an ActiveX control with .NET?

I've found some tutorials on the web, but they all expect you to have the assembly installed on your local machine, and registered and trusted both it and the website that's accessing it.

This is asking a bit much for potential anonymous internet users, and even for intranet users another method of deployment would be preferable.

I distinctly remember some website asking me to download this or that ActiveX control. And on pages requiring such browser plugins as Flash and Java, there is some mechanism by which the browser knows where to fetch the plugin for that media type.

So my question is twofold:

- Can I create a control that can run in the user's browser in .NET?
- What is the best method of (semi-)automatic delivery that I can achieve?

---

In response to Sunny:

Yes, a lot of JavaScript rich text editors allow you to paste a **linked image** into a text field, and it will insert the correct <img> tag. However, this only works for images that already have a location on the web, and I want this to upload new images just by copy/pasting any random bitmap from your clipboard.

Comment: I would really recommend avoiding hacking in clipboard functionality unless it is absolutely core functionality to your web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're okay with IE only, I like the IE hosted control's security model over Active-X, however, as of 1/1/09, Microsoft deprecates the use of .NET (in process) to extend IE so XBAP is okay, but not in ActiveX controls or IE Hosted controls.

Update 7/13: Microsoft has published [guidance on implementing in-process extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); it's still deprecated.

Edit: W/o tweaking the registry, IE8 will only load a .NET hosted control from the intranet or trusted zone so for general internet use, Active-X is required for in-browser full trust access.

To follow up on Russ's post:  Silverlight can't access the clipboard: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/13024.aspx

Most of the IE hosted control information is in blogs so I use: http://www.google.com/search?q=ie+hosted+control+site:msdn.com to find them.  Below are the ones I've found particularly useful.

Quick and easy control: http://blogs.msdn.com/mikechr/archive/2006/11/28/writing-a-simple-managed-control-under-ie.aspx

Odd thing about security, unless the "evidence" is a url, the assembly may be trusted, but not the domain, requiring asserts to fix: http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2006/11/01/code-access-security-hosting-control-in-ie.aspx

This is "fixed" in 3.5 with manifests. It's complicated to get right so see the  instructions on using manifests from Shawnfa's .NET Security Blog for the [.NET 3.5 Beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2007/03/09/manifests-for-ie-hosted-controls.aspx) and [post GA .NET 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2008/01/24/manifested-controls-redux.aspx).  Todd's Random Discovery blog also documents the [steps for creating a manifest for a hosted control](http://rrandomdiscovery.blogspot.com/2009_05_01_archive.html)

I found this useful from a KB article on setting up the security, but you'll still have to learn quite a bit about CAS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892466. This is probably the main consideration when deciding to use a (.net) Active-X vs an IE hosted control - that is, what security model works best for you and your users.  My hope is that using manifest will make IE hosted controls work like click-once where the user is asked to "trust" and the correct settings are created by the system. For my company we used could automate setting up the security for the user so an ie hosted was our choice.

The one thing I never figured out was if I did or didn't have to inherit from (User)control for a ui-less control.  It worked better for me to do so, but I had to "hide" the div the object tag lived in.

It's easy to debug the control if you compile for debug and attach to IE for "managed" debugging once you get the control to load.  If you can't get the control to load, look up info on the fusion assembly binding viewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx and how to turn on IEHost tracing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313892 in order to debug the load process.

Be sure to version every version of the assembly.  If you don't, then IE gets confused and won't load the control when the assembly in the download cache is different but has the same version # as the one the url references (gacutil /cdl clears the .net download cache)

Answer (score 2):

Lookup "Winforms hosted in IE". I had to do something similar a few years back, and thats where I was finialy able to make some head way.

Two things to note: As you may have noticed, this questions doesn't come up very often, so examples are limited. ( I no longer have any to share, sorry ). Also, .NET's security model is much different than the COM based ActiveX, so getting this to work in the different security zones of IE will be a tad bit tricky.

If you have the ability to use Silverlight 2, I would probibly lean in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveX limits you to IE and Windows only. Better take a look at google docs and/or gmail to see how they handle pasting an image in your email/online document using javascript only. Works OK with most browsers and OS out there.

Comment: i wonder if image-paste in gmail and gdocs are supported only in HTML5 browsers?