# Creating a plugin for webbrowsers

Tags: .net, flash, pdf, plugins, browser

I want to create plugins similar to that of flash and the .pdf viewers.  Could somebody point me in the right direction?  What languages are required.  Can I use any language?  .Net?

Thanks if you can!

Comment: what browsers? what platform?

Comment: Well, flash is for basically any browser.  I want some ability like that.  For now though, just consider say... google chrome or IE. // Windows most likely.  Perhaps linux as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I think this answers my question here:

[Creating and deploying an ActiveX control in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299323/creating-and-deploying-an-activex-control-in-net)

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't support ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

For a great deal of non-IE plugins, use NPAPI.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI

For IE, you will have to write an ActiveX version.

I believe you can use any framework or language you wish as long as you can wrap it up in NPAPI and ActiveX. Also, you might need a cross-platform library to run it on multiple operating systems.

Comment: I don't think normal plugins will work will they?  How do you make the big plugins such as Flash and Pdf viewers?  Are they made any way differently than normal plugins?

Comment: Flash has NPAPI and ActiveX implementations. Adobe Reader is the same way, I think.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense.  How does flash put the objects on the page though?  I know that NPAPI (at least on GC) doesn't allow you to edit the page until it has completely loaded.